# Авторизация на определенный URL по паролю

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Хочу авторизовать юзеров через авторизацию посредством apache по определенному URL-у (не имеет значения роль пользователя): *mysite.ru/web/url/index*

на форме нашел [тему](https://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?t=12829), но немогу додумать, сейчас есть .htaccess следующего вида:

```
RewriteEngine on

# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /web/url/index [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php

SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/index\.php/url/index" ADMIN_PASSWD=true
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/url/index" ADMIN_PASSWD=true
SetEnvIf Request_URI "url/index" ADMIN_PASSWD=true

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Thats protected Area!"
AuthUserFile //var/www/html/www/mysite.ru.htpasswd
Order Allow,Deny
Satisfy any
Allow from all
Require valid-user
Deny from env=ADMIN_PASSWD
<Files .htpasswd>
   deny from all  #запрет доступа из браузера к .htpasswd
</Files>
```

После подсказки @eustatos мой .htaccess стал таким:

```
RewriteEngine on

# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php


SetEnvIf Request_URI "url/index" require_auth=true

AuthUserFile /var/www/html/www/mysite.ru.htpasswd
AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthType Basic

# Setup a deny/allow
Order Deny,Allow
# Deny from everyone
Deny from all
# except if either of these are satisfied
Satisfy any
# 1. a valid authenticated user
Require valid-user
# or 2. the "require_auth" var is NOT set
Allow from env=!require_auth
```

но после авторизации возникает ошибка 500 Internal Server Error, есть идеи по этому вопросу?

Comment: А вопрос то будет? или это повествование о ваших приключениях?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, добавил вопрос.

Comment: Отвечая на ваш вопрос: с помощью директив apache записать их можно в файл конфигурации apache или в .htaccess. p.s. может вы теперь свяжете вопрос из последнего предложения с остальным текстом? Сейчас лично я читаю ваш "текст" как: "у меня есть зеленый крокодил, я нашел на форуме инструкцию к красной игуане. Мой вопрос следующий как мне сделать фиолетового попугая"

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, что тут не понятного? есть URL, я предпринял попытки скрыть его средствами аутентификации apache, c использованием .htaccess и .htpasswd, но у меня не получается, так как нет великих знаний в этом вопросе.

Comment: А непонятно мне вот что: У вас есть файл, в нем есть директивы, которые для вас выглядят как магия, вы не удосужились даже глянуть что они означают и как работают файлы .htaccess, зато прибежали на форум чтобы вам помогли найти **вашу ошибку**. Ваша ошибка - в нежелании разбираться а **не в указаном вами файле**. Так вот мне не понятны ваши шаги после того как вы скопипастили **чужой** кусок кода. Непонятно мне почему вы пришли на этот сайт, а не в документацию например или на фриланс.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков вот тут вы ошибаетесь, я час рыл интернет в поиске готового решения, после того как попытка была неудачна я решил разобрать пример из ссылки на форуме, но к сожалению у меня не получилось, на данный момент с помощью приведенного выше .htaccess я могу спрятать от всех пользователей сети нужный мне url, правда сервер выдаст ошибку 500, но все же прогресс. SetEnvIf Request_URI вот это ключевой момент и вот это Deny from env=ADMIN_PASSWD, что туда можно написать что бы решить мой вопрос? Можете скинуть ссылки на нужны док. может у меня что то не получилось найти, спасибо!

Comment: Вот я вам ровно то же и сказал, вы ищите готовое решение =) не имея ни толики желания разобратся в сути =) читайте, сразу говорю - на готовое что есть в статье не расчитывайте =) не выйдет =) http://www.codenet.ru/webmast/apache/Apache-Access.php

Comment: http://www.4stud.info/networking/apache-directives.html и вот еще, комбинируйте то что в первой и второй статье =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков подскажите что это ADMIN_PASSWD=true значит? и чем по вашему можно его заменить?

Comment: Он вам вообще не нужен

Comment: У вас версия апач случаем не 2.4? Ибо в ней не сработает как минимум эта строка `Order Deny,Allow`

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков версия 2,4, а на что ее можно заменить?

Comment: Не нужно ее заменять ни на что. Замените комманды на верные для apache 2.4( у вас конфигурация для apache 2.2)

Answer (score 1):

В директории, которую нужно защитить паролем создайте файл .htaccess

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Thats protected Area!"
AuthUserFile /usr/host/mysite/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
<Files .htpasswd>
   deny from all  #запрет доступа из браузера к .htpasswd
</Files>
```

и файл .htpasswd, содержащий пары логин-пароль (зашифрованный).
В linux файл можно создать с помощью команды из `apache-utils`

```
htpasswd -c <path-to-file> <login>
```

Или с помощью [онлайн-генераторов](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=.htpasswd%20generate%20online&lr=51&clid=2186621)

Comment: у меня есть htpasswd, выше каталогом, мне надо не директорию защитить а конкретный URL. Так как использую Yii есть с этим проблемы.

Comment: @MaximLyubitelev, в Yii все запросы направляются в index.php. И там уже происходит роутинг.
Думаю что средствами apache защитить паролем конкретный url, который ведет на несуществующий файл\папку, не получится.

Comment: имеет ли право на жизнь статья из форума, что я прикрепил к вопросу?

Comment: apache под рукой нет, чтобы попробовать. Вот нашел аналогичное [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603568/password-protect-a-specific-url)

Comment: возникает 500 Internal Server Error после авторизации, в вопросе произвел правку, есть у вас идеи по этому поводу?